# WP_Query is not working on the custom pages

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm trying to output Team Members on the page.
I have created two custom post types "team-member" and "occupation" and assigned ACF fields to them, so each team member have a occupation associated using relationship option at ACF.
All works ok, until I try to output the Team Members on the page for example `page-services.php`.
The Query works on `single-occupation.php` with no problems which is my single post template, showing the correct team member for particular occupation, but is not working on other custom pages like mentioned `page-services.php`

My Query:

```
<?php
    $relatedTeamMembers = new WP_Query(array(
        'posts_per_page' => -1,
        'post_type' => 'team-member',
        'orderby' => 'title',
        'order' => 'ASC',
        'meta_query' => array(
        array(
            'key' => 'related_occupation',
            'compare' => 'LIKE',
            'value' => '"' . get_the_ID() . '"'
        )
        )
    ));

    if ($relatedTeamMembers->have_posts()) {

        echo '<ul>';
            while($relatedTeamMembers->have_posts()) {
                $relatedTeamMembers->the_post(); ?>
                    <li>
                        <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
                            <img src="<?php the_post_thumbnail_url(); ?>">
                            <span><?php the_title(); ?></span>
                        </a>
                    </li>
            <?php }
        echo '</ul>';
    }
    wp_reset_postdata();
?>
```

I don't have any errors just nothing outputted on the page. I have also used `wp_reset_postdata()` function even if I do not run multiple queries on the same page, but this doesn't help.
I would be super grateful if someone could help me to understand what I'm doing wrong here...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are not in the single page of the post type, there is no reference to a single post using `get_the_ID()`.

On your custom page, you have not defined what the id of the occupation should be. So the query has no match with the `value` you are looking for in your `meta_query`.

If you want to output a specific occupation, you will have to set an id.
Assuming the id of your occupation (you see it in the url on mouse over in the backend) is '1049', your code could look like:

```
'meta_query' => array(
        array(
            'key' => 'related_occupation',
            'compare' => 'LIKE',
            'value' => '1049' // id of occupation
            )
        )
```

Comment: OMG how stupid I am! Thanks so much, I've spent couple of hours looking for the solution, this make sens now! Once again thank you so much!